# How can I add a prefix to all routes with the Flask REST JSON module?

Tags: python, flask

The [flask-rest-jsonapi quickstart](https://flask-rest-jsonapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html) shows that you can create a `route()` like this:

```
api.route(PostList, 'post_list', '/posts')
api.route(PostDetail, 'post_detail', '/posts/<int:id>')
```

But I want to have all of my routes to be something like `/api/posts` and `/api/poss/<int:id>` and I want to avoid repeating the `/api` part in every `route()`. When I try to use a blueprint here, like this:

```
api_bp = Blueprint('API', __name__, url_prefix='/api')
api = Api(app, api_bp)
api.route(PostList, 'post_list', '/posts')
api.route(PostDetail, 'post_detail', '/posts/<int:id>')
app.register_blueprint(api_bp)
```

The endpoint is still `/posts` and not `/api/posts`. How do I properly make a URL prefix for all the routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the discussions on [Github](https://github.com/miLibris/flask-rest-jsonapi/issues/35#issuecomment-327698322) do the following:

```
# Create blueprint
api_bp = Blueprint('API', __name__, url_prefix='/api')

# Create Api instance only passing the blueprint
api = Api(blueprint=api_bp)

# register routes
api.route(PostList, 'post_list', '/posts')
api.route(PostDetail, 'post_detail', '/posts/<int:id>')

# initialize Api instance to App
api.init_app(app)
```

Don't forget that the view names will change. i.e view `'post_list'` becomes `'API.post_list'` so you have to adjust your schemes, but not your route declarations. This is also discussed in the linked Github discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use flask and Flask-RESTful here. You just need to create flask APP first and configure Flask-RESTful API with prefix.

Here is the example

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app, prefix="/api")
```

Now you can add resource to the api.route as below

```
import types
api.route = types.MethodType(api_route, api)


def api_route(self, *args, **kwargs):
"""Add resource to the api route"""
    def wrapper(cls):
        self.add_resource(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return cls
```

Comment: Does this have a way to auto-generate SQLAlchemy bindings the way `flask-rest-jsonapi` does?

Comment: I am not sure about `flask-rest-jsonapi` but you can use `Flask-SQLAlchemy`. It is offering a auto-generate bindings. Here I found some documents that might help you. Flask-SQLAlchemy: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/sqlalchemy/, Binding: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/#:~:text=What%20are%20binds%3F,key%20(the%20bind%20key).